# How has Earth's atmospheric water been in previous eras and periods?

Tags: water, atmospheric-science, gas, geophysics, evaporation

How has partial pressure and net amount of water vapor and colloidal water been in previous eras and periods on Earth?

Comment: As long as there are oceans, it all comes down to temperatures. During the ice-ball periods the amount of water vapor was lower...

Comment: @JonCuster Not only temperature. Nucleation conditions are critical for precipitation.

Comment: What does "colloidal water" mean in this context?

Comment: @DavidBailey Small water droplets and ice. Maybe they don't fulfil the criteria of being insoluble, but at the conditions they exist they don't dissolve into air. Should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the Earth's atmospheric water content is strongly dependent on atmospheric temperature, with an [expected absolute increase in atmospheric water vapour of about](https://www.carbonbrief.org/guest-post-investigating-climate-changes-humidity-paradox/)
$7\%/\textrm{K}$.  The *relative* humidity - the ratio of atmospheric moisture to storage capacity - may, however, decrease with increasing temperature.

For example, the total absolute water content of the atmosphere (in all forms: vapour, clouds, water droplets, ice crystals, …) will be lower in ice ages, but the Earth's average relative humidity  [may be higher](https://doi.org/10.1038/245129a0). This is because although there is less oceanic evaporation, the cooler air also cannot hold as much water and convection driven precipitation generating mechanisms may be less efficient, so water stays in the atmosphere longer.

This is consistent with what has been [observed in recent decades](https://www.carbonbrief.org/guest-post-investigating-climate-changes-humidity-paradox/) as the Earth's has warmed; the amount of moisture in the atmosphere has increased while the Earth's average relative humidity has decreased.

These relative humidity changes are small, however, because it is difficult for the Earth's relative humidity to change too much. If the air get's too dry, precipitation slows down and water builds up in the atmosphere until eventually it rains or snows. For example, when [modelling the Precambian atmosphere](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/28446/0000234.pdf?sequence=1), it was assumed that the average relative humidity would be similar to today.

**Supplement in response to comment question about whether "convective precipitation" is dominant:**

Convection driven precipitation is likely more than half of all precipitation, but determining a precise value is difficult both observationally and theoretically.
[Parameterizing atmospheric convection](https://doi.org/10.1080/07055900.2022.2082915) "is the long-lasting bottleneck of global climate modelling and one of the most difficult problems in atmospheric sciences".

Precipitation mechanisms are [often categorized as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precipitation_types#Mechanisms), :

- *Convective*: occurs when warm moist air rises vertically because of convection and cools as it rises until the moisture condenses into [cumulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulus_cloud) or [cumulonimbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulonimbus_cloud) clouds and eventually falls as precipitation.
- *Stratiform*: when warm moist air meets and is forced up by a cold air masses forming [nimbostratus clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbostratus_cloud), e.g. frontal systems.
- *Orographic*: when moist air is forced up by land geography, e.g. mountains.

Note: A single weather system such as tropical storm can have both convective and stratiform driven precipitation (and even orographic if the storm hits mountains), so it can be tricky to determine their relative fractions.

Orographic precipitation is obviously not dominant, since as noted in [this Earth Science SE answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/253/27775) and this [NASA webpage](https://science.nasa.gov/earth-science/oceanography/ocean-earth-system/ocean-water-cycle), almost 80% of precipitation occurs over the ocean where there there is negligible land geography.

Measurements from satellites such as the [Tropical Rainfall Measuring Mission](https://gpm.nasa.gov/missions/trmm) (TRMM) show that convective precipitation dominates over the tropics and subtropics where the [Earth's heaviest precipitation occurs](https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data/gpcp-monthly-global-precipitation-climatology-project), while stratiform is more common at higher latitudes. (See, for example, [Figures 3 & 4 in this paper](https://doi.org/10.3390/rs9111142).) I can't immediately find a consensus number for the convective-to-total precipitation ratio (PC/PR). According to [Table 1 of this paper](https://doi.org/10.1029/2020jd034198), global climate models typically have PC/PR around 0.7, but the value for different models can range from 0.4 to 1.0.

Comment: Regarding "convection driven precipitation generating mechanisms may be less efficient". Is this the dominant precipitation factor? Can convection driven precipitation be determined better?

Comment: @David-Jonsson I have supplemented my answer with some information about what we know about how much precipitation is convective.